# Referencing Android Activity View from a Singleton object

Tags: android, android-activity, view, singleton

Suppose I have an Android Activity (`SecondaryActivity`), which is started from `MainActivity`

SecondaryActivity contains a text view, `TextView tv;`

I have a Singleton that looks something like this:

```
public class Singleton {
    private static final Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    private static TextView secTextView;

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void setTV(TextView tv){
        secTextView = tv;
    }

    public TextView getTV(){
        return secTextView;
    }
}
```

In my `SecondaryActivity` I do:

```
Singleton.getInstance().setTV(findViewById(R.id.sec_text_view));
```

Now imagine later I run `finish()` inside `SecondaryActivity` so the program state returns back to `MainActivity`, popping `SecondaryActivity` off the Activity stack.

And now imagine `MainActivity` runs

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext, SecondaryActivity.class));
```

once again.

After this, if I run

```
Singelton.getInstance().getTV().setText("hello world"));
```

will we be referencing the `TextView` within the Activity currently at the top of the Activity stack?

Also, is there any obvious problems with my approach in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will we be referencing the TextView within the Activity currently at
>   the top of the Activity stack?

Only if you run `Singleton.getInstance().setTV(findViewById(R.id.sec_text_view));` in the `onCreate` method of your second activity.

> Also, is there any obvious problems with my approach in general?

YES!! You should not put views/activity references in static classes/fields. You are creating memory leaks. When you call finish from the `SecondaryActivity` your singleton still references the text view and the activity can't be garbage collected. This leaks memory.

When you start `SecondaryActivity` again, a new instance of `SecondaryActivity` is created. Unless you call `setTV` again your singleton still references the text view from the finished activity.

Here is a [blog post](https://techbeacon.com/what-you-need-know-about-android-app-memory-leaks) with more information about memory leaks.

If you want to simplify view binding you should take a look at [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/).

Comment: To help with leaks you can set the static reference to null.

Comment: @dazza5000 what is the point of the singleton then? Views belong in the activity scope.

Comment: I would not recommend using a singleton like this, but was suggesting a way to help with memory leaks if you choose to do so.